# Blackberry file upload webworks extension with progress bar

Tags: cordova, blackberry, progress-bar, blackberry-webworks

In my blackberry webworks project, I have to implement file upload feature. Is there any extension for webworks which gives progress callback for fileupload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 file upload api

You can refer

http://robertnyman.com/2010/04/22/using-the-file-api-for-reading-file-information-multiple-file-uploads-another-sister-specification-to-html5/